# Let's do some CAP (Cosmology, Astronomy and Physics)

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, outer-space

[image]

**ACROSS**

> 5 God of agriculture
>    8 Time travel
>   14 Not in Australia...
>   16 A friend of mine and 800 suns
>   17 Still growing...
>   18 Proposed capital Lambda
>   19 56 + 36 + 3(0)

**DOWN**

> 1 Nearest to our G-dwarf
>    2 This is really a powerful pit!
>    3 Prefix of an element and a ship.
>    4 A giant with a pit in it.
>    6 A gemstone and a cloud of ions, dust, and gases
>    7 Desert and Cosmology
>    9 R shift
>   10 One of the brightest cloud of ions, dust, and gases
>   11 Rotate zike
>   12 On a long journey
>   13 Mickey's ......
>   15 Areal velocity...

Comment: What I got so far: (feel free to use in answers) rot13(Npebff: 5 - Fnghea, 17 - Havirefr Qbja: 4 - Gnegnehf)

Comment: @Duck 5 and 17 are correct but 4 is not.

Comment: rot13(1 - Cebkvzn Pragnhev, 2 - Oynpx ubyr, 10 - Bevba, 18 - pbafgnag)

Comment: Correct! If you wish, post it as a partial answer. @MariiaMykhailova

Comment: rot13(Gjb qbja oynpx ubyr; ryrira qbja xrmv.)

Comment: Ak19, any feedback on my new guesses and @aml's ones?

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova Your 19 is correct and both of amI's are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1 - [Proxima Centauri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxima_Centauri)
>  
>  2 - black hole
>  
>  3 - [Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(moon)) (prefix of titanium and Titanic)
>  
>  4 - Jupiter (from El-Guest's comment)
>  
>  5 - [Saturn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_%28mythology%29) (from Duck's comment)
>  
>  6 - Cat's Eye ([nebula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat%27s_Eye_Nebula)/[gemstone](https://www.gemselect.com/other-info/cats-eye-gems.php))
>  
>  7 - [Atacama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atacama_Cosmology_Telescope) 
>  
>  8 - [tachyon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) (from amI's comment)
>  
>  9 - [Hubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) (from amI's comment)
>  
>  10 - [Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_Nebula)
>  
>  11 - [Vega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vega) (= rot22(zike))
>  
>  12 - Voyager (from Bananenkopp's comment)
>  
>  13 - [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_(Disney)) (from Bananenkopp's comment)
>  
>  14 - Aurora borealis (can not be seen from Australia) (from Bananenkopp's comment)
>  
>  15 - Kepler
>  
>  16 - [Omega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Nebula) ("The total mass of the Omega Nebula is an estimated 800 solar masses." - not sure what's the story with the friend is though)
>  
>  17 - universe (from Duck's comment)
>  
>  18 - [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant)
>  
>  19 - Uranus (the products of a nuclear fission of Uranium-235 are two light nuclei of Krypton and Barium, elements 36 and 56 in periodic table)

This was some serious teamwork!

Comment: maybe rot13(8 - gnpulba, 9 - Uhooyr)

Comment: 4 looks like rot13(Whcvgre).

Comment: I think you can add rot13(14 - "Nheben obernyvf" (pna abg or frra sebz Nhfgenyvn)) and rot13(12 - "Iblntre" (Rnegu'f Snegurfg Fcnprpensg)) and rot13(13 - "Cyhgb")

Comment: Really an excellent team work! Just a correction, please check the spelling of Jupiter.

Comment: Ah, that's how you can tell that I've been working with Jupyter Notebooks for the past three months :-D

Comment: The hint to 16 (a friend of mine...): I think he adresses the user "OmegaKrypton", @Ak19 right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. ; )